# How to debug crashes with question marks in XCode's organizer?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crash

Since our last release we're seeing weird crashes in the Xcode Organizer containing only question marks. I first thought that these were unsymbolicated crashes but Xcode says these are already symbolicated.

[image: Xcode Organizer]

It looks a bit like this issue: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5043 but only half of the list of crash reports contains something like this, the rest is even more empty..

Here's the text log (App name [REDACTED])

```
Incident Identifier: 1A154CE4-CDF0-4256-B9D8-70946ED34B20
CrashReporter Key:   7865bd097344620404f5964c78ee2d2ca62076d2
Hardware Model:      iPad3,6
Process:             [REDACTED] [5171]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/92158CF3-A62A-44F5-A7F7-5B409D8ACEC8/[REDACTED].app/[REDACTED]
Identifier:          [REDACTED]
Version:             [REDACTED]
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           [REDACTED] [1437]


Date/Time:           2020-05-05 21:47:11.8672 +0200
Launch Time:         2020-05-05 21:47:09.0000 +0200
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.3.4 (14G61)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000001
Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x1dafef52 free + 176 (malloc.c:491)
1   ???                             0x00000400 0 + 1024

Thread 1 name:
Thread 1:
0   [REDACTED]                      0x006b3ac0 -[APMMeasurement swapBackgroundTaskWithNewTaskID:] + 0
1   [REDACTED]                      0x006a5bcc -[APMMeasurement initWithAppID:isAnalyticsCollectionEnabled:isAnalyticsCollectionDeactivated:] + 1034
2   [REDACTED]                      0x006a4836 +[APMMeasurement initializeSharedInstanceWithAppID:isAnalyticsCollectionEnabled:isAnalyticsCollectionDeactivated:] + 158
3   [REDACTED]                      0x0068e8f0 __46+[APMAnalytics startWithAppID:origin:options:]_block_invoke_2 + 64
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x1d9c5796 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10 (init.c:963)
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x1d9d259c _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 854 (inline_internal.h:2431)
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x1d9c8b70 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 886 (queue.c:4853)
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x1d9d41b4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 326 (inline_internal.h:2468)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x1d9d400e _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 106 (queue.c:5550)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1db7a87c _pthread_wqthread + 1040 (pthread.c:2196)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1db7a45c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1db7a454 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3 name:
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x1dac4568 __bsdthread_ctl + 12
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1db803be _pthread_qos_override_end_direct + 16 (qos.c:472)
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1d586dd4 rwlock_tt<false>::unlockRead() + 44 (objc-os.h:1045)
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1d586d06 lookUpImpOrForward + 414 (objc-runtime-new.mm:4945)
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1d586b64 _class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache3 + 26 (objc-runtime-new.mm:4804)
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1d58d1ae _objc_msgSend_uncached + 14
6   Foundation                      0x1eb82670 +[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) _new:] + 34 (NSRunLoop.m:149)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x1e208eae _CFRunLoopGet2 + 110 (CFRunLoop.c:1647)
8   Foundation                      0x1eb50152 +[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) currentRunLoop] + 20 (NSRunLoop.m:160)
9   Foundation                      0x1eb4fe40 +[NSObject(NSDelayedPerforming) cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:selector:object:] + 76 (NSRunLoop.m:703)
10  [REDACTED]                      0x006dab18 -[APMUserDefaults scheduleSynchronize] + 56
11  [REDACTED]                      0x006da34a -[APMUserDefaults setObject:forKey:] + 568
12  [REDACTED]                      0x006b9cf2 __39-[APMPersistedConfig setString:forKey:]_block_invoke + 48
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x1d9d1a34 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 50 (queue.c:3446)
14  [REDACTED]                      0x006b9c9c -[APMPersistedConfig setString:forKey:] + 130
15  [REDACTED]                      0x006a675a __47-[APMMeasurement startMeasurementOnWorkerQueue]_block_invoke + 590
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x1d9c5782 _dispatch_client_callout + 22 (init.c:1023)
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x1d9c6252 dispatch_once_f + 42 (once.c:57)
18  [REDACTED]                      0x006a64da -[APMMeasurement startMeasurementOnWorkerQueue] + 398
19  [REDACTED]                      0x006a6102 -[APMMeasurement setEnabledOnWorkerQueue:] + 236
20  [REDACTED]                      0x006bd000 __51-[APMScheduler scheduleOnWorkerQueueBlockID:block:]_block_invoke + 92
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x1d9c5796 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10 (init.c:963)
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x1d9d259c _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 854 (inline_internal.h:2431)
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x1d9c8b70 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 886 (queue.c:4853)
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x1d9d41b4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 326 (inline_internal.h:2468)
25  libdispatch.dylib               0x1d9d400e _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 106 (queue.c:5550)
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1db7a87c _pthread_wqthread + 1040 (pthread.c:2196)
27  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1db7a45c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 4 name:
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x1dab0900 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x1dab06e0 mach_msg + 44 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1e2b3be2 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 144 (CFRunLoop.c:2527)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x1e2b2064 __CFRunLoopRun + 1436 (CFRunLoop.c:2870)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x1e2051ae CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470 (CFRunLoop.c:3113)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x1e204fd0 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104 (CFRunLoop.c:3143)
6   Foundation                      0x1eb59af4 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 258 (NSRunLoop.m:367)
7   Foundation                      0x1eb7676c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 86 (NSRunLoop.m:411)
8   UIKit                           0x23e88ad8 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 128 (UIEventFetcher.m:313)
9   Foundation                      0x1ec3d8ea __NSThread__start__ + 1122 (NSThread.m:1163)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1db7c93a _pthread_body + 216 (pthread.c:697)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1db7c85c _pthread_start + 234 (pthread.c:744)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1db7a468 thread_start + 8

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x1dac673c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1db7a8ea _pthread_wqthread + 1150 (pthread.c:2205)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1db7a45c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 6 name:
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x1dab0900 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x1dab06e0 mach_msg + 44 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1e2b3be2 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 144 (CFRunLoop.c:2527)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x1e2b2064 __CFRunLoopRun + 1436 (CFRunLoop.c:2870)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x1e2051ae CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470 (CFRunLoop.c:3113)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x1e204fd0 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104 (CFRunLoop.c:3143)
6   Foundation                      0x1eb59af4 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 258 (NSRunLoop.m:367)
7   Foundation                      0x1eba6db8 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 80 (NSRunLoop.m:389)
8   [REDACTED]                      0x00632ba4 +[GAI threadMain:] + 64 (GAI.m:240)
9   Foundation                      0x1ec3d8ea __NSThread__start__ + 1122 (NSThread.m:1163)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1db7c93a _pthread_body + 216 (pthread.c:697)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1db7c85c _pthread_start + 234 (pthread.c:744)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1db7a468 thread_start + 8

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1db7a454 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x1dac673c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1db7a8ea _pthread_wqthread + 1150 (pthread.c:2205)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1db7a45c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 9 name:
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x1dab0900 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x1dab06e0 mach_msg + 44 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1e2b3be2 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 144 (CFRunLoop.c:2527)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x1e2b2064 __CFRunLoopRun + 1436 (CFRunLoop.c:2870)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x1e2051ae CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470 (CFRunLoop.c:3113)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x1e204fd0 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104 (CFRunLoop.c:3143)
6   CFNetwork                       0x1e8e2392 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 402 (NSURLConnection.mm:364)
7   Foundation                      0x1ec3d8ea __NSThread__start__ + 1122 (NSThread.m:1163)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1db7c93a _pthread_body + 216 (pthread.c:697)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1db7c85c _pthread_start + 234 (pthread.c:744)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1db7a468 thread_start + 8

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x1dac673c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1db7a8ea _pthread_wqthread + 1150 (pthread.c:2205)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1db7a45c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1db7a454 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000001    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000003      r3: 0x00b98a40
    r4: 0x3a534068    r5: 0x16d5bae0      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x16e6d6e0
    r8: 0x00b98980    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x54000cf8     r11: 0x00000001
    ip: 0x02a6ff68    sp: 0x00b98950      lr: 0x00007800      pc: 0x1dafef52
  cpsr: 0x20000030
```

Comment: This is the first release build with Xcode 11.4.1, previous one was build with 11.0. Could that be causing this?